# Falsely deemed as spam question is counted against me?

Tags: bug, spam, post-ban

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573810/how-can-i-get-rid-of-blurry-textures-in-metal) question that was deemed spam in my desperate attempts to get an answer. I guess those are ineffective, so I learned my lesson. It was deleted as spam, I can tell in the history of the question.

Then Cody Gray undeleted it realising it is not spam. I am glad that Cody was kind enough to give the question a second chance, but later it said that I could not submit due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from my network.

So I read the help center and am asking this question from an alternate location. Why are *falsely* deleted spam question still being held against me. It is supposed to take me more than one question that gets downvoted to be denied and asked to take a breather and come back soon.

My question was deleted as spam, but being not spam it was undeleted, but why is it still being held against me as if it were actually spam?

Comment: Instead of spam I think it is more likely that question got rude/abusive flags, given the various edits that you made to add utter non-sense to your question. That kind of abuse is red-flagged and those flags are held against you for good reason as you made those edits willingly and repeatedly. But let's wait for a mod to confirm my theory.

Comment: it wasn't flagged as spam but rude/abusive, probably because of "WTF" stuff all caps contained in the first revision.

Answer (score 21):

Spam is a total red herring. There was never any indication or annotation that the question was spam.

It *was*, however, flagged as "rude or abusive" by a community member. When I first saw that flag, I declined it, because the question in the form I saw it was clearly not "rude or abusive". That would make the flag invalid.

But then, after dismissing the flag, I took a closer look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60573810/revisions). Several of the revisions, like revision 7 and revision 8, are indeed what I would classify as "rude or abusive"—emphasis on the "abusive" part. [Filling your question with nonsense is an abuse of the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035), and I regularly validate flags on that sort of absolute gibberish.

So then, I had to figure out what to do. The "rude or abusive" flag was valid at the time it was raised, but then someone else had edited the question into shape, removing all of the gibberish and going above and beyond to try and turn it into a legitimate question.

One option was just to leave the "rude or abusive" flag marked as "declined", under the theory that the flagger should have removed the gibberish and fixed the question, rather than flagging as "rude or abusive". I didn't like this option, though, because folks who try to evade our quality standards by filling their question with nonsense shouldn't be so accommodated by our community. Questions like that *should* be nuked with "rude or abusive" flags. So, in an attempt to make up for the fact that I'd missed the edit history, I cast a "rude or abusive" flag of my own on the question, and then *cleared all* "rude or abusive" flags, which has the effect of marking all "rude or abusive" flags as "disputed". This is a bit of a hack, but it allowed me to access that third, in-between "disputed" state that "rude or abusive" flags (unlike other moderator flags) can take on.

The summary is, I felt that I'd declined the "rude or abusive" flag too quickly, so I made up for it using a workaround where I flagged it myself, cleared the flag, and thus marked both "rude or abusive" flags as "disputed" (instead of "declined").

**Other than having your question briefly deleted and then re-instated, that process was completely transparent and irrelevant to you.** Your question is no longer annotated in any way as "rude or abusive", and it remains open, ready to receive an answer.

You really have nothing to complain about here. You were treated *more than fairly* by both moderators and the community.

**As for why your account is currently forbidden to ask questions, see here: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)** It is not uncommon to be restricted from asking more questions when your very first question is deemed as very low quality by the community. This assessment was made based on downvotes, and was based on the quality of the question *as the voters saw it*.

(To be clear: when a post is flagged as "spam" or "rude or abusive", automatic downvotes are cast on it by a bot. However, these downvotes are removed whenever those flags are cleared, which is what I did here. So you are not getting penalized in any way from spam or rude/abusive flags. You are, however, getting penalized for the garbage that you originally posted, which attracted downvotes, before some kind soul edited it. You only have one chance to make a good first impression. You blew it. Sorry.)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not going to address your actual question about why you're currently being blocked from posting, because knowing why you're blocked requires being a moderator. [I'd previously guessed wrong that you were blocked by [SpamRam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310356/271271).] However, I feel there's benefit to both you and others in going over what happened on your question, at least as far as I can tell without the benefit of being a moderator and seeing the history of flags on the question.

Saying "Falsely deemed as spam question" in your title on this Meta Stack Overflow question is is a bit disingenuous. While the [version that was actually deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60573810/9) wasn't spam or rude/abusive (spam/R/A), the [revisions which *you authored* prior to your question being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60573810/8) were both spam (trying to promote your question within the list of questions; e.g. your "CLICK HERE ----->...<-----" title) and rude/abusive (i.e. the excessive begging in all caps, which is considered yelling, was "inappropriate for respectful discourse"). In other words, what you wrote was, in fact, spam and/or rude/abusive.

That it was spam and/or offensive resulted in your question getting red-flags (i.e. spam flags and/or rude/abusive flags). Those flags resulted in a moderator responding to the flags and deleting the question as rude/abusive. Briefly deleting your question was necessary in order to have the flags end up in the most appropriate state. Please see [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394487/3773011) for more detail.

However, your question was rescued by someone else putting the effort in to edit-out ([revision 9 here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60573810/revisions)) the spam/rude/abusive text which you'd intentionally added with a series of edits, each edit making the question more and more like spam/rude/abusive content. So, while I agree that the version which was deleted wasn't any of those (and it was undeleted within 5 seconds of being deleted), there's nothing in the record of that question which indicates to the system that you've "learned your lesson" and won't be posting similar content.

Frankly, even from what you've written in your question here it doesn't really sound like you've "learned your lesson", because the only lesson you indicate you've learned is that such text is "ineffective", rather than indicating you understand that what you wrote was offensive to the people which you're wanting to have donate their time and expertise in order to help you. Basically, yes, the pragmatic view is that such text is not just ineffective, but is actively harmful with respect to getting people to help you. However, what you really should learn is that such text/demonstrated attitude is offensive to a large percentage of the people who might help you.

Comment: The account is *not* blocked by SpamRam.

Comment: @CodyGray Good to know. Looks like you ninja'd me wrt. answering. :-)  BTW: My assumption is that moderators can see if an account is blocked by SpamRam, but not detailed information as to *why* an account is blocked by SpamRam. Is that accurate?

Comment: It seems I was able to ninja you on posting an answer because you posted drafts in the comments. :-p There are only a small number of reasons why an account would be blocked by SpamRam. So, although moderators cannot see the direct reason why, it is not that difficult to figure out with a bit of additional poking around. In addition to SpamRam status, we can also see that an account is post-banned (either question or answer). But in that case, no, we cannot see why, and that is much more difficult to determine.